# Firestore Rules | Insufficient permission when using resource.data on getting collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My firestore rules

```
match /fruits/{fruit} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user;
}
```

Now on reading a single document, there is no problem

```
db.collection("fruits").doc('apple').get()
```

but when I try to get the collection, it gives me **permission-denied**

```
db.collection("fruits").get()
```

Comment: Where is clientId present? In order document or file sub-document? Can you share their example ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj both documents have `clientId` in them

Comment: Security rules do nothing until you exercise them through code or in the playground. Can you edit your question to include the [minimum code that we can run against these rules to get the problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found out what the exact problem is.... and i have update my question

Comment: If you get a permission_denied on that read operation, I recommend logging `firebase.auth().currentUser` right before running it to ensure the user is indeed signed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to query all documents in 'fruits' collection, the security rules check if `user` field in those documents is equal to UID of user requesting data. If any one document doesn't match the condition, it'll throw a permission error. Instead you should add a `where()` clause in your query as shown below:

```
db.collection("fruits").where("user", ==, currentUserUID).get()
```

This query will find documents where user field matches user's UID and all matched docs will pass the security rule `if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user;`. Security rules are not filters and that means they won't filter out documents from collection based on the rule. You must write a query that way.